# auth0 implementation in MERN- Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Object]?

Tags: node.js, mern, auth0

Trying to implement some auth0 authentication for the first time into a mern stack. I think the problem might be how I'm importing checkJwt but I'm not positive. I have tried wrapping checkJwt in { checkJwt } as well, same problem. Edit: if I remove the checkJwt parts just to see if it still launches, I get 'jwt is not a function' error. I'm getting the error:

> throw new Error(msg); Error: Route.get() requires a callback function
> but got a [object Object]

backend/routes/articleRoutes:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const ArticleModel = require("../models/articles");

const checkJwt = require("../index");
const authz = require('express-jwt-authz');

  
// Get all articles
router.get("/", checkJwt, authz(['read:article']), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const articles = await ArticleModel.find();
    res.json({
      count: articles.length,
      data: articles,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});

// Get one article by id
router.get("/:id", checkJwt, authz(['read:article']), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const article = await ArticleModel.findById(id);
    if (!article) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: "Article not found!" });
    }
    res.status(200).json(article);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});

// Create a new article
router.post("/", checkJwt, authz(['create:article']), async (req, res) => {
  const {
    category,
    type,
    name,
    born,
    died,
    nationality,
    known_for,
    notable_work,
    about,
    year,
    medium,
    dimensions,
    location,
    designed_by,
    developer,
  } = req.body;
  const article = new ArticleModel({
    category,
    type,
    name,
    born,
    died,
    nationality,
    known_for,
    notable_work,
    about,
    year,
    medium,
    dimensions,
    location,
    designed_by,
    developer,
  });
  try {
    const newArticle = await article.save();
    res.status(201).json(newArticle);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(400).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});

router.put("/:id", checkJwt, authz(['update:article']), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const article = await ArticleModel.findByIdAndUpdate(id, req.body, {
      new: true,
    });
    if (!article) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: "Article not found!" });
    }
    res.status(200).json(article);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});

// Delete an article
router.delete("/:id", checkJwt, authz(['delete:article']), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const article = await ArticleModel.findByIdAndDelete(id);
    if (!article) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: "Article not found!" });
    }
    res.status(200).json({ message: "Article deleted successfully!" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

backend/index.js:

```
// This file is the entry point for the backend server.
require("dotenv").config();

const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const articleRoutes = require("./routes/articleRoutes");
const cors = require("cors");

const authz = require('express-jwt-authz');
const jwksRsa = require('jwks-rsa');
const jwt = require('express-jwt');

const checkJwt = jwt({
  // Validate the audience and issuer from your Auth0 application
  audience: 'HIDENCODE',
  issuer: 'HIDENCODE',
  algorithms: ['RS256'],
  secret: jwksRsa.expressJwtSecret({
    cache: true,
    rateLimit: true,
    jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
    jwksUri: 'HIDENCODE',
  }),
});

module.exports = checkJwt;

// Get environment variables
const MONGO_STRING = process.env.MONGO_STRING;
const PORT = process.env.PORT;

// Connect to MongoDB database
mongoose.connect(MONGO_STRING, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

const database = mongoose.connection;

database.on("error", (error) => {
  console.log("Error connecting to database:", error);
});

database.once("connected", () => {
  console.log("Connected to database");
});

// Create express app
const app = express();

// Middleware for parsing JSON and handling CORS policy
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

// Routes
app.use("/articles", articleRoutes);

// Start server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```